# what is correct ODBC connection string in mac excel?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I try to use code below to operate data in mac excel.

But it will pop the message "General ODBC error".

The code works fine in Windows environment(Didn't pop any dialog).

How to fix this in mac environment?

I wonder if it need modify the connection string to support mac.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim sqlstr As String
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    
    sqlstr = "select * from [OrderData$]"
    
    Set qt = ExecuteQuery(sqlstr)
    Debug.Print "query result rows count:" & UBound(qt.ResultRange.Value)

End Sub

Function ExecuteQuery(sqlstr As String) As QueryTable

    Dim connstring As String
    Dim wbName As String
    Dim wsResult As Worksheet
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    
    Set wsResult = Worksheets("QueryResult")
    
    wsResult.Cells.Clear
    
    For Each qt In wsResult.QueryTables
        qt.Delete
    Next qt
    
    wbName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        
    connstring = "ODBC;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" + wbName + ";UID=\;PWD=;"

    With wsResult.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=wsResult.Range("A1"), sql:=sqlstr)
      .BackgroundQuery = False
      .Refresh
    End With
    

    Set ExecuteQuery = wsResult.QueryTables(1)

End Function
```